# How can fill drawable to area where I want?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

[image]

This is current chart.

I want to fill drawble to only part of chart.

Like this marked box on picture

[image]

My dataset is here.

```
    val dataSet = LineDataSet(entry, "")
    dataSet.setDrawCircles(false)
    dataSet.setDrawCircleHole(false)
    dataSet.setDrawFilled(true)
    dataSet.fillDrawable = if (context?.resources != null) {
        context?.resources?.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_selected_range_graph)!!
    }
    else {
        MyApp.instance().resources.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_selected_range_graph)
    }
    dataSet.mode = LineDataSet.Mode.CUBIC_BEZIER
    dataSet.cubicIntensity = 0.3f
    dataSet.lineWidth = 0f
    dataSet.fillAlpha = 0
    dataSet.color = lineColor
    dataSet.setDrawValues(false)

    contentView.chart.data = LineData(dataSet)
```

Comment: A useful article https://proandroiddev.com/building-a-custom-view-a-practical-example-2753cb9d0e80

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

In my case, I have to use range seekbar.

So, if minValue/maxValue is set, Chart need update.

1. divide data to 3 list
2. first/third list will be none selected graph, second list will be selected graph
3. convert each list to DataSet.
4. second DataSet fill drawable 'selectedColorDrawable'
5. chart.data = LineData(set1, set2, set3)
6. chart.invalidate()
7. finish